# issus with render a rectangle on dx11(metro style app)

Tags: directx, microsoft-metro

i want draw a rectangle on screen
but something wrong ,i cannot see anything on my screen.
i'm using  dx11 (metro style app)
the shader code is the same  with Sample Code(D3D-Cude Sample) in VS 2012

anyone give me some suggestion?

here is my code below:

```
// get color

    COLOR4F clr = m_SytleInterface->GetBackGroundDefaultClr();
            VPOINTF3 ptDes[4];
            VFloat iWidth = 256.0;
            VFloat iHeight = 256.0;
            VFloat fLX = -466.0;
            VFloat fBY = -819.0;
    //set world view projection matrix
            g_constantBufferData.world = 
    XMMatrixTranslation(-116.5, -204.75, 0) * CVBGL::m_world;
            g_constantBufferData.view = CVBGL::m_view;
            g_constantBufferData.projection = (XMMATRIX)CVBGL::m_projection;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC constantBufferDesc = {0};
    constantBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(g_constantBufferData);
            constantBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
            constantBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
            constantBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
            constantBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
            //constantBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(
                    &constantBufferDesc,
                    nullptr,
                    &m_constantBuffer
                    )
                );
            m_d3dContext->UpdateSubresource(
                    m_constantBuffer.Get(),
                    0,
                    nullptr,
                    &g_constantBufferData,
                    0,
                    0
                );
    //init Vertex
            ptDes[0].x = 0.0f;
            ptDes[0].y = 0.0f;
            ptDes[0].z = 0.0f;
            ptDes[1].x = 0.0f;
            ptDes[1].y = 256;
            ptDes[1].z = 0.0f;
            ptDes[2].x = 256;
            ptDes[2].y = 256;
            ptDes[2].z = 0.0f;
            ptDes[3].x = 256;
            ptDes[3].y = 0.0f;
            ptDes[3].z = 0.0f;

    ByteArray loadVSTask = ReadData("SimpleVertexShader.cso");
            ByteArray loadPSTask = ReadData("SimplePixelShader.cso");

            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_d3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(
                    bytecodeVS->Data,
                    bytecodeVS->Length,
                    nullptr,
                    &vertexShader
                    )
                );

            const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC basicVertexLayoutDesc[] =
            {
                { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
                { "COLOR",  0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            };

            ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> inputLayout;
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_d3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(
                    basicVertexLayoutDesc,
                                  ARRAYSIZE(basicVertexLayoutDesc),
                                  bytecodeVS->Data, 
                                  bytecodeVS->Length,
                                  &inputLayout)
                                );
            m_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout.Get());

            ComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader> pixelShader;
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(
                    bytecodePS->Data,
                    bytecodePS->Length,
                    nullptr,
                    &pixelShader
                    )
                );

            VertexPositionColor  Vertices[4] =
            {
                { XMFLOAT3(ptDes[0].x, ptDes[0].y, ptDes[0].z), XMFLOAT4( clr.fRed, clr.fGreen, clr.fBlue, clr.fAlpha) }, // +Y (top face)
                { XMFLOAT3(ptDes[1].x, ptDes[1].y, ptDes[1].z), XMFLOAT4( clr.fRed, clr.fGreen, clr.fBlue, clr.fAlpha) },
                { XMFLOAT3(ptDes[2].x, ptDes[2].y, ptDes[2].z), XMFLOAT4( clr.fRed, clr.fGreen, clr.fBlue, clr.fAlpha) },
                { XMFLOAT3(ptDes[3].x, ptDes[3].y, ptDes[3].z), XMFLOAT4( clr.fRed, clr.fGreen, clr.fBlue, clr.fAlpha) },
            };

            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc = {0};
            vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VertexPositionColor) * ARRAYSIZE(Vertices);
            vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
            vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
            vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
            vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
            //vertexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

            D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData;
            vertexBufferData.pSysMem =Vertices;
            vertexBufferData.SysMemPitch = 0;
            vertexBufferData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

            ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexBuffer;
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_d3dDevice->CreateBuffer(
                    &vertexBufferDesc,
                    &vertexBufferData,
                    &vertexBuffer
                    )
                );

            UINT stride = sizeof(VertexPositionColor);
            UINT offset = 0;
            m_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(
                0,
                1,
                vertexBuffer.GetAddressOf(),
                &stride,
                &offset
                );

 // Specify the render target and depth stencil we created as the output target.
                m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(
                    1,
                    m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(),
                    m_depthStencilView.Get()
                    );

                // Clear the render target to a solid color, and reset the depth stencil.
                const float clearColor[4] = { 0.071f, 0.04f, 0.561f, 1.0f };
                m_d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(
                    m_renderTargetView.Get(),
                    clearColor
                    );

        m_d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);

            m_d3dContext->VSSetShader(
                vertexShader.Get(),
                nullptr,
                0
                );

            m_d3dContext->PSSetShader(
                pixelShader.Get(),
                nullptr,
                0
                );

            m_d3dContext->Draw(4,0);

            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_swapChain->Present(1, 0)
                );
```